# SQL Consecutive Repetance of Values by Row

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
id            calltime                   call_end 
1001   2020-04-05 12:00:00.000            answered
1002   2020-05-05 13:23:02.000            not answered
1002   2020-05-05 13:25:02.000            not answered
1002   2020-05-05 13:28:02.000            answered
1002   2020-05-06 13:23:02.000            not answered
...
```

I'm trying to add a new column that ranks the call_end column by id, but I want the rank to reset to 1 when the call_end value changes. For example:

```
id            calltime                   call_end       rank
1001   2020-04-05 12:00:00.000            answered       1
1002   2020-05-05 13:23:02.000            not answered   1
1002   2020-05-05 13:25:02.000            not answered   2
1002   2020-05-05 13:28:02.000            answered       1
1002   2020-05-06 13:23:02.000            not answered   1
...
```

However, when I use the RANK() OVER (partition by id, call_end order by calltime) it gives me the following ranking:

```
id            calltime                   call_end       rank
1001   2020-04-05 12:00:00.000            answered       1
1002   2020-05-05 13:23:02.000            not answered   1
1002   2020-05-05 13:25:02.000            not answered   2
1002   2020-05-05 13:28:02.000            answered       1
1002   2020-05-06 13:23:02.000            not answered   3
...
```

Is there a way to reset the ranking to 1 when the consecutive values stop?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution, using `lag()` to compare the previous row and `sum over` to identify the differences:

with sample data

```
create table t (id int, calltime datetime, call_end varchar(20))
insert into t values
(1001,'20200405 12:00:00.000','answered'),
(1002,'20200505 13:23:02.000','not answered'),
(1002,'20200505 13:25:02.000','not answered'),
(1002,'20200505 13:28:02.000','answered'),
(1002,'20200506 13:23:02.000','not answered')


with c as (
    select Id, CallTime, Call_End, sum(case when call_end = call_endPrev then 0 else 1 end)  over(order by calltime rows unbounded preceding) as diff 
    from (
        select *, Lag(call_end) over(partition by id order by call_end) call_endPrev
        from t
    )x
)
select Id, CallTime, Call_End, row_number() over(partition by id, diff order by call_end) as [Rank]
from c
order by id, calltime
```